How to access app dependency in FastAPI when not injecting to endpoint
FastApi app is defined in main.py. I need to do some initialization where I load from a database into a cache.
When my app runs normally, it calls a get_db() function to return a SqlServer session and this get_db function is used in endpoints using session=Depends(get_db) in the parameters.
I need some kind of call to get the correct get_db function based on app dependencies, so that it will use the overrode version defined in testconf.py when I'm running pytests. How do I do this?
#database.py
engine = create_engine("sqlserver connection string here")
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False,autoflush=False,bind=engine)
def get_db():
   # standard way to get db in FastAPI
   db = SessionLocal()
   yield db

#main.py
from database import get_db

# When running pytests, its not finding the override version in 
# in the app dependencies
if fn := app.dependency_overrides.get(get_db):
    sess = next(fn())  
else:
    sess = next(get_db())
CacheService.load_cache(sess) 

#testconf.py
#defines fixtures used by pytests
@pytest.fixture 
def engine():
  url = "sqlite://"
    return create_engine(url, ...)

@pytest.fixture
def app_session(engine):
  TestingSessionLocal = sessionmaker(..., bind=engine)
  def override_get_db():
      db = TestingSessionLocal()
      yield db
  app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db
  return app

@pytest.fixture
def client(app_session):
    return TestClient(app=appsession)

#some test
def test_something(app_session, client):
# It loads the caches using a sqlserver session 
   client.get("url")
   


I'm seeing that fastapi has a lifespan function that can be called when the app starts up.  Its a function that takes one arg: a FastAPI app object.  So this won't work for me because I can't inject the get_db dependency into so that it has a database session.   How could this be?  It would be natural to do database operations when starting up the app?   In fact, when I set a breakpoint in the function, its not even getting called when I'm running my pytests so maybe its not part of the startup when running the TestClient?

Could you use a specific set of configuration values instead of trying to replace the dependency? From your example it seems like the difference is the connection string (and possibly the two parameters to create_engine) - since your code is evaluated in the same places as app is defined, that code will be evaluated before being handed over to have the dependency override registered.

I think I get you.   Since the get_db dependency hasn't been replaced by the time main.py is running,  I can't expect to use it and get the right db for testing which gets replaced in the fixtures as explained by @ViAchKoN .  Not sure how I would set the configuration values.  The connection string to the db is what changes based on whether I'm running normally or running tests.   Where/how would I be setting these config values based on whether its a test or normal run?

These line don't do what you expect because the project is initialized before fixtures are applied.
if fn := app.dependency_overrides.get(get_db):
   sess = next(fn())  
else:
   sess = next(get_db())

That means, that python first reads database.py, main.py and other files nessasary to run fastapi/project and only after that it starts a test run with loading all the fixtures. So basically the order how tests are run is:

Initializing a project
Loading fixtures
Starting fake fastapi client
Running a test

As long as you want to CacheService.load_cache(sess) be in the file you won't be able to use a mocked session by the CacheService.load_cache method. This could be solved by moving it to a method with a decorator @app.on_event("startup") (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/):
@app.on_event("startup")
async def init_services() -> None:
   CacheService.load_cache(get_db())

Also, you will need to mock session used by get_db(). You can do it by updating fixtures:
@pytest.fixture
def fake_session(engine):
   return sessionmaker(..., bind=engine)

@pytest.fixture
def client(fake_session):
   with TestClient(app) as client:
       # path to SessionLocal 
       database.SessionLocal = fake_session. # you can also use mocker patch here 
       yield client



The @app.on_event("startup") gives a message that its deprecated in FastAPI and that I should use lifespan functions instead.  I've tried using both but find that neither one gets called when I'm running my tests.  This seems odd to me.  The lifespan function does get called when I run my app normally so I'm putting my call to load my cache from the database in that function so that the app will correctly initialize when it runs normally.

How did you checked that @app.on_event("startup") is not used? We have the same project structure and I can confirm that @app.on_event("startup") before starting an app.

Here is what I did to test that the startup handler function was not called while running pytests:   1.  Set breakpoint in function and ran in debugger - never got there. 2. Put print and logger.info statements in there - none emitted.  3 Opened a file and wrote some data into it, closed file.   - no file found after running tests.

I would be hard to tell what is the issue without looking at the complete code. I mean without looking at how you define the app and use @app.on_event("startup") . But I can confirm that I have the project structure which utilizes fastapi events and it works as expected.

I'm taking advantage of what seems to be a fact: that the lifespan function runs on startup when normally running the app but NOT when testing.   My evidence being in my lifespan function, I've set debugger breakpoints, added print statements, and had it write to a file  None of these took place when running tests based on the fastapi TestClient.   So my lifespan function can use get_db and call my cache_load method and that takes care of the case of running the app normally.   For handling the case of loading the cache when testing, I went into a fixture (not shown in my original post) that takes as input the engine .  This fixture seeds the database with the necessary rows of data for running the app and testing it.  Following the seeding, it gets a Session from the engine and then calls the CacheService to load caches.  It works
#main.py
@aynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app:FastAPI):
  sess = next(get_db()) #uses normal sqlserver db
  CacheService.load_cache(sess)
  yield

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

#conftest.py
@pytest fixture
def seeded_db(engine):
  # engine will be the sqlite db 
  with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(text("insert into table..."))
    ...
    conn.commit()
    session = Session(engine)
    CacheService.load_cache(session)
  yield engine
  session.close()


There should be no difference whether it is a test run or an actual one. The app is initialized the same way. If it were otherwise, there would be no point in tests because you wouldn't be able to check the whole application.
P.S Probably better to update the initial answer than posting updates in the answer section.

I agree, but this was not my experience as described in my comment above.   I got the same behavior with lifespan function which is why I took that route.
